# How to enable ESLint for TypeScript files in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, eslint, visual-studio-2019

I have ESLint enabled in the Tools/Options under Text Editor/Javascript/TypeScript/Linting/General:

[image]

but I don't see any evidence that it's actually working.  I tried writing code that triggers ESLint in VS Code, but nothing is happening in Visual Studio 2019.  For reference, it's a .NET Core Web Project.

What am I missing?

P.S. Not sure if VS 2019 uses, but I do have ESLint installed (via NPM) and working in Visual Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio didn't support Typescript at the time this question was asked. 
For anyone viewing the question now, as of VS 2019 version 16.5, it finally supports Typescript:

https://github.com/microsoft/JSTSdocs/blob/master/articles/editor/linting.md